# unexpected value return by array variable

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to pass array to function (*getcreditcurve). I am expecting function (*getcreditcurve) to return an array. Main function is expected to send several such array to function (*getcreditcurve), pointer function is expected to return a array to main function for different array using the logic given in pointer function (*getcreditcurve). I am not getting error but I don’t get correct value. I expect I+1 to be 3 * 0.0039 = 0.0117 and I+2 to be 4 *0.0060 = 0.0024 however I get following in excel output

```
'00D4F844   00D4F84C'
```

Even if I change the print statement to

```
'print << *(I1+1) << '\t' << *(I2+2) << endl;'
```

I get following excel out put

```
-9.26E+61   -9.26E+61
```

Can somebody help in trouble shooting please? Sorry I went through other post/question in this site but not able to get simplest way to solve this issue. I am going to use this logic to build other projects so simplified the question just to resolve main issue.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
typedef double S1[5];
using namespace std;
double *getcreditcurve(double *);

int main()
{


S1 C1 = { 0.0029, 0.0039, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.0057 };
S1 C2 = { 0.0020, 0.0050, 0.0060, 0.0070, 0.0080 };

typedef double *issuer;
issuer I1 = getcreditcurve(C1);
issuer I2 = getcreditcurve(C2);


ofstream print;
print.open("result1.xls");
    print << (I1+1) << '\t' << (I2+2) << endl;

    print.close();
    return 0;


}

double *getcreditcurve(S1 ptr)
{
const int cp = 5;
typedef double curve[cp];
curve h;

h[0] = 2 * ptr[0];
h[1] = 3 * ptr[1];
h[2] = 4 * ptr[2];
h[3] = 5 * ptr[3];
h[4] = 6 * ptr[4];

return h;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope Arrays do not copy implicitly. That's one reason why they are not very handy and should be replaced by `std::array`.

Comment: [Scope vs. Lifetime of Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137516) seems to be a near duplicate... storing a pointer to a variable that has gone out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `getcreditcurve` to return an array, then try this:

```
const int cp = 5;
typedef double curve[cp];
curve getcreditcurve(S1 ptr) {
```

But that gives an error `error: ‘foo’ declared as function returning an array`. Functions can't return C arrays. But the good news is that if you fully embrace C++ you can return `std::array` instead.

```
#include<array>
const int cp = 5;
typedef curve std::array<double,cp>;
curve getcreditcurve(S1 ptr) {
```

But really, `std::vector` is probably much better as you have more flexibility about the size.

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<double> getcreditcurve(std::vector<double> ptr)
{
    std::vector<double> h;
    h.push_back(2 * ptr.at(0));
    h.push_back(3 * ptr.at(1));
    h.push_back(4 * ptr.at(2));
    h.push_back(5 * ptr.at(3));
    h.push_back(6 * ptr.at(4));

    return h;
}
```

In fact, pretty much all problems with C arrays can be solved by `std::vector`. Then, in special situations, you can use `std::array`. But focus on `std::vector` for now.

Comment: ok I will try vector but just to confirm " typedef curve std::array<double,cp>;" or "std::vector<double> getcreditcurve(std::vector<double> ptr)" is to change getcredit curve function only. I have written my ain project with lots of array. Sp more try to use array but conceptually array and vector will work same (keeping aside size issue?

Comment: You will have to make many more changes. Basically, you should avoid `*` totally (except, of course, for multiplication).  You'll have to write `vector<int> C1 { 0.0029, 0.0039, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.0057 };` to define C1 as a vector also. I know this seems like a lot of work, but it really is better to just avoid `*`-pointers in C++

Comment: Also, you must be *very* clear when you use the word "array". You should say "C array" when discussing the kind of arrays your are using now `e.g. char c[5]`, and you should say "`std::array`" when talking about the improved arrays in C++11. I will try to be clear in future. Most people, when they say "array", mean "C array", but it might be better to be clear always

Comment: I see another comment related to "storing a pointer to a variable that has gone out of scope." So do I have to use "new" feature in addition asI am paasing different arrays

Comment: @Kausik, if you use `std::vector` or `std::array`, and if you avoid pointers and avoid `new` and `delete`, then you will not need to worry about memory allocation and problems such as pointers going out of scope. But yes, if you have a C array as a local variable, then you should not return it. (I might now add another answer to show an easy way to solve this)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to return a C array from a function. There are other things you can return, such as `std::vector` or `std::array`. You should consider redesigning your application around those two instead.

But if you really need to use C arrays in C++, I suggest that instead of trying to return an array from `getcreditcurve`, you pass an extra array into `getcreditcurve` which will be used to store the result. This is called an output parameter.

```
void getcreditcurve(double*, double *);
```

This would solve the "scope" problem. The caller (`main`) would then create the array before calling `getcreditcurve` and would then pass that to `getcreditcurve`. As a result, `getcreditcurve` does not have to take responsibility for creating (or destroying) any object.

```
double I1[5];
getcreditcurve(I1, C1); // will store its result on `I1`.
```

This might be the easiest option if you really really need to get this working as soon as possible.

---

If you are willing to make some further changes, you can make a much safer program. The short term goal is to abolish all uses of `*` (except to use it for multiplication).

C arrays cannot be passed by value, in particular they cannot be returned. There are other funky things you can do (passing special pointers), but the best thing to do with C arrays is to pass them *by reference*. In C++, reference-passing behaviour is quite consistent and works well.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362360/unexpected-value-return-by-array-variable
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
typedef double S1[5];
using namespace std;

/* In the following declaration, the two parameters
 * are taken by reference (note the '&').
 * This is almost always the best way to pass arrays.
 *
 * Also, this is a template where N is automatically
 * set to the correct number of parameters. This nice
 * automatic behaviour is possible only because the
 * array is taken by reference.
 *
 * Finally, note that the second reference, for 'input',
 * has 'const'. This is to emphasize that 'input' is for input,
 * that getcreditcurve will not be allowed to modify the input argument.
 */
template<size_t N>
void getcreditcurve(double (&output)[N],const double (&input)[N]);

int main()
{


    /* S1 is the type - array of five doubles */
    /* Here declare and initialize C1 and C2 as two variables
     * of this type */
    S1 C1 = { 0.0029, 0.0039, 0.0046, 0.0052, 0.0057 };
    S1 C2 = { 0.0020, 0.0050, 0.0060, 0.0070, 0.0080 };

    // create the two output arrays first, within main
    S1 I1;
    S1 I2;
    // call getcreditcurve, passing in the output and input arrays
    getcreditcurve(I1,C1);
    getcreditcurve(I2,C2);


    ofstream print;

    /* you can't create Excel(.xls) files in C++ easily
     * Better to just create a .csv file instead
     * csv = comma-separated values
     */
    print.open("result1.csv");
    print << I1[0] << ',' << I2[3] << endl;

    print.close();
    return 0;

}

template<size_t N>
void getcreditcurve(double (&output)[N],const double (&input)[N])
{
    output[0] = 2 * input[0];
    output[1] = 3 * input[1];
    output[2] = 4 * input[2];
    output[3] = 5 * input[3];
    output[4] = 6 * input[4];
}
```

But seriously, you really should just ditch C arrays entirely. This is C++, not C. Use `std::vector<double>` instead.