# How to use or free dynamically allocated memory when I run the program multiple times?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do I free dynamically allocated memory?

Suppose input (assume it is given by user) is 1000 and now if I allocate memory of 1000 and after this(second time) if user gives input as 500 can I reuse already allocated memory ?

If user now inputs value as say 3000 , how do I go with it ? can I reuse already allocated 1000 blocks of memory and then create another 2000 blocks of memory ? or should I create all 3000 blocks of memory ?

which of these is advisable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct a
{
  int a;
  int b;
}aa;

aa* ptr=NULL;
int main() {
//code
int input=2;
ptr=malloc(sizeof(aa)*input);

for(int i=0;i<input;i++)
{
    ptr[i].a=10;
    ptr[i].b=20;
}

for(int i=0;i<input;i++)
{
    printf("%d  %d\n",ptr[i].a,ptr[i].b);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `realloc` to make the allocation bigger. `realloc` will attempt to increase the size of the memory. If it can't increase the size of the allocation, it will A) allocate a new memory block B) copy the data to the new memory C) deallocate the old memory.

Comment: The workflow is `alloc`, then any number of `realloc` calls, then a `free`.

Comment: first user gives input as 500 ,500 blocks of memory will allocated . now second time when i execute user gives 1000 , so now i need to use already allocated 500 blocks and add 500 blocks of memory , how do i do in my code . and 3rd time say user gives 300 as input from already allocated 1000 blocks of memory i need to reuse the memory. How do i do this safely without any warnings/errors.

Comment: @bbcbbc1 That is why, to avoid these sort of confusions, if not anything else, you should `free()` the allocated memory before program ends. The usage would be much more clear then.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, you need to read about [the "lifetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11137516/2173917) of allocated memory.

For allocator functions, like `malloc()` and family, (quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3, for "Memory management functions")

> [...] The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
>   until the deallocation. [....]

So, once allocated, the returned pointer to the memory remains *valid* until it is deallocated. There are two ways it can be deallocated

- Using a call to `free()` inside the program
- Once the program terminates.

So, the allocated memory is available, from the point of allocation, to the termination of the program, or the `free()` call, whichever is earlier.

---

As it stands, there can be two aspects, let me clarify.

- Scenario 1:

  ```
  You allocate memory (size M)
  You use the memory
  You want the allocated memory to be re-sized (expanded/ shrinked)
  You use some more
  You're done using
  ```

  is this is the flow you expect, you can use `realloc()` to resize the allocated memory size. Once you're done, use `free()`.
- Scenario 2:

  ```
  You allocate memory (size M)
  You use the memory
  You're done using
  ```

  If this is the case, once you're done, use `free()`.

*Note: In both the cases, if the program is run **multiple times**, there is no connection between or among the allocation happening in each individual invocation. They are independent.*

Comment: hi , my requirement---    First user gives input as 500 ,500 blocks of memory will allocated . now second time when i execute user gives 1000 , so now i need to use already allocated 500 blocks and add 500 blocks of memory , how do i do in my code . and 3rd time say user gives 300 as input from already allocated 1000 blocks of memory i need to reuse the memory. How do i do this safely without any warnings/errors.   How do i proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use dynamically allocated memory, and adjust its size, it is important to keep track of exactly how many elements you have allocated memory for.

I personally like to keep the number of elements in use in variable named `used`, and the number of elements I have allocated memory for in `size`. For example, I might create a structure for describing one-dimensional arrays of doubles:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t  size; /* Number of doubles allocated for */
    size_t  used; /* Number of doubles in use */
    double *data; /* Dynamically allocated array */
} double_array;
#define DOUBLE_ARRAY_INIT { 0, 0, NULL }
```

I like to explicitly initialize my dynamically allocated memory pointers to `NULL`, and their respective sizes to zero, so that I only need to use [`realloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html). This works, because `realloc(NULL, size)` is exactly equivalent to `malloc(NULL)`. I also often utilize the fact that `free(NULL)` is safe, and does nothing.

I would probably write a couple of helper functions. Perhaps a function that ensures there is room for `at_least` entries in the array:

```
void double_array_resize(double_array *ref, size_t at_least)
{
    if (ref->size < at_least) {
        void *temp;

        temp = realloc(ref->data, at_least * sizeof ref->data[0]);
        if (!temp) {
             fprintf(stderr, "double_array_resize(): Out of memory (%zu doubles).\n", at_least);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ref->data = temp;
        ref->size = at_least;
    }

    /* We could also shrink the array if
       at_least < ref->size, but usually
       this is not needed/useful/desirable. */
}
```

I would definitely write a helper function that not only frees the memory used, but also updates the fields to reflect that, so that it is completely safe to call `double_array_resize()` after freeing:

```
void double_array_free(double_array *ref)
{
    if (ref) {
        free(ref->data);
        ref->size = 0;
        ref->used = 0;
        ref->data = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is how a program might use the above.

```
int main(void)
{
    double_array  stuff = DOUBLE_ARRAY_INIT;

    /* ... Code and variables omitted ... */

    if (some_condition) {
        double_array_resize(&stuff, 321);

        /* stuff.data[0] through stuff.data[320]
           are now accessible (dynamically allocated) */
    }

    /* ... Code and variables omitted ... */

    if (weird_condition) {
        /* For some reason, we want to discard the
           possibly dynamically allocated buffer */
        double_array_free(&stuff);
    }

    /* ... Code and variables omitted ... */

    if (other_condition) {
        double_array_resize(&stuff, 48361242);

        /* stuff.data[0] through stuff.data[48361241]
           are now accessible. */
    }

    double_array_free(&stuff);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I wanted to use the `double_array` as a stack, I might do

```
void double_array_clear(double_array *ref)
{
    if (ref)
        ref->used = 0;
}

void double_array_push(double_array *ref, const double val)
{
    if (ref->used >= ref->size) {
        /* Allocate, say, room for 100 more! */
        double_array_resize(ref, ref->used + 100);
    }

    ref->data[ref->used++] = val;
}

double double_array_pop(double_array *ref, const double errorval)
{
    if (ref->used > 0)
        return ref->data[--ref->used];
    else
        return errorval; /* Stack was empty! */
}
```

The above `double_array_push()` reallocates for 100 more doubles, whenever the array runs out of room. However, if you pushed millions of doubles, this would mean tens of thousands of `realloc()` calls, which is usually considered wasteful. Instead, we usually apply a *reallocation policy*, that grows the size *proportionally to the existing size*.

My preferred policy is something like (pseudocode)

```
If (elements in use) < LIMIT_1 Then
    Resize to LIMIT_1
Else If (elements in use) < LIMIT_2 Then
    Resize to (elements in use) * FACTOR
Else
    Resize to (elements in use) + LIMIT_2
End If
```

The `LIMIT_1` is typically a small number, the minimum size ever allocated. `LIMIT_2` is typically a large number, something like 2<sup>20</sup> (two million plus change), so that at most `LIMIT_2` unused elements are ever allocated. `FACTOR` is between 1 and 2; many suggest `2`, but I prefer `3/2`.

The goal of the policy is to keep the number of `realloc()` calls at an acceptable (unnoticeable) level, while keeping the amount of allocated but unused memory low.

The final note is that you should only try to keep around a dynamically allocated buffer, if you reuse it for the same (or very similar) purpose. If you need an array of a different type, and don't need the earlier one, just `free()` the earlier one, and `malloc()` a new one (or let `realloc()` in the helpers do it). The C library will try to reuse the same memory anyway.

On current desktop machines, something like a hundred or a thousand `malloc()` or `realloc()` calls is probably unnoticeable compared to the start-up time of the program. So, it is not that important to minimize the number of those calls. What you want to do, is keep your code easily maintained and adapted, so logical reuse and variable and type names are important.

The most typical case where I reuse a buffer, is when I read text input line by line. I use the POSIX.1 [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function to do so:

```
char   *line = NULL;
size_t  size = 0;
ssize_t len;  /* Not 'used' in this particular case! :) */

while (1) {
    len = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    if (len < 1)
        break;

    /* Have 'len' chars in 'line'; may contain '\0'! */
}
if (ferror(stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading standard input!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Since the line buffer is no longer needed, free it. */
free(line);
line = NULL;
size = 0;
```