# Arduino code section is not repeating at proper time

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm new to C++ and Arduino, but for a class project, I started working on a simple Arduino calculator. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(5, 4, 3, 2, A4, A5);



const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {A0, A1, 11, 10}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int LCDRow = 0;


Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.setCursor(LCDRow, 0);
    lcd.print("Enter first");
    lcd.setCursor (++LCDRow, 15);
    lcd.print("number");
}

void loop(){
    char key = keypad.getKey();


    int firstNumber = 0;
    int selecting = 1;
    int secondNumber = 0;

    if (key && selecting == 1){
        key = key - 48;
        firstNumber = key;
        lcd.setCursor(LCDRow, 0);
        lcd.clear();
        selecting = 2;
        lcd.print("Selected");
        lcd.setCursor (++LCDRow, 15);
        lcd.print(firstNumber);
        delay(2000);
        lcd.clear();
    } 
    key =  0;
    if (selecting == 2){
        lcd.print("Enter second");
        lcd.setCursor (++LCDRow, 15);
        lcd.print("number");
    }

    if (key && selecting == 2){
        key = key - 48;
        secondNumber = key;
        lcd.setCursor(LCDRow, 0);
        lcd.clear();
        selecting = 3;
        lcd.print("Selected");
        lcd.setCursor (++LCDRow, 15);
        lcd.print(secondNumber);
        delay(2000);
        lcd.clear();
    } 
    key =  0;
    if (selecting == 3){
        lcd.print("Enter");
        lcd.setCursor (++LCDRow, 15);
        lcd.print("operation");
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to ask you to input a number, input a second number, then ask to input an operation (plus, minus, etc.). I have not completed the code for actually inputting an operation yet, but I don't know if that is causing the issue.

Currently, after selecting the second number, it asks to input the second number again. Does anyone know what I've done wrong? (Everything's being outputted to a generic 16x2 LCD display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here, at the start of `loop`:

```
void loop(){
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    int firstNumber = 0;
    int selecting = 1;
    int secondNumber = 0;
```

Each time loop is run, these variables are effectively recreated from scratch - they do not preserve their value from previous runs of `loop`. So `selecting` will be reset to `1` each time `loop` is run.

A good primer on variable lifetime is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137516/scope-vs-lifetime-of-variable).

You can fix this by making the variables `static`:

```
void loop(){
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    static int firstNumber = 0;
    static int selecting = 1;
    static int secondNumber = 0;
```

This means they will preserve their value through multiple runs of `loop`.

Comment: I attempted to make this change; however, doing so causes the "Enter second number" text to endlessly repeat after choosing the first number.

Comment: Since you only need to print those prompts once, they can go just after the delays for the previous number.

Comment: This seems to fix everything. I'm accepting the answer now, thanks!