# How do we add an event in C++/WinRt project?

Tags: c++-winrt

I am currently work on a C++/WinRt which connects(Sender) to one of the available devices(Client) around a specific region using WifiDirect. When the device wants to connect, it sends a connection request to the sender. The sender needs to detect the connection request sent by the client and connect to the client. For this I need to add an event - (On Connection requested). As soon as I add it should execute the code of OnConnectionRequested.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include "winrt/Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.h"
#pragma once
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
```

```cpp
enum class NotifyType
{
    StatusMessage,
    ErrorMessage
};
```

```cpp
enum class CallbackContext
{
    Any,
    Same
};
```

```cpp
class st
{
public:
    void OnConnectionRequested(WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender,
                               WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgsconnection EventArgs)
    {
        WiFiDirectConnectionRequest connectionRequest = connectionEventArgs.GetConnectionRequest();
        printf("Connection request received from ", connectionRequest.DeviceInformation().Name(), "Connection Request");
        printf("Connecting to ", connectionRequest.DeviceInformation().Name(), NotifyType::StatusMessage);
    }
    
    void start()
    {
        Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect::WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher _publisher;
        Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect::WiFiDirectConnectionListener _listener;
        winrt::event_token _connectionRequestedToken;
    
        try
        {
            _connectionRequestedToken = _listener.ConnectionRequested({this, &st::OnConnectionRequested});
            _publisher.Start();
            printf("Advertisement started, waiting for StatusChangedcallback...", NotifyType::StatusMessage);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            printf("Error starting Advertisement: ", NotifyType::ErrorMessage);
        }

        getchar();
    }
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    st s;
    s.start();
}
```

Is this the right way to add an event in C++/WinRt :

```
_connectionRequestedToken = _listener.ConnectionRequested({this, &st::OnConnectionRequested});
```

The errors are :

> LNK1120 1 unresolved externals   - error in Winrt.exe file
>
> LNK2019
> unresolved external symbol "public: struct winrt::hstring __thiscall
> winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_IDeviceInformation::Name(void)const
> "
> (?Name@?$consume_Windows_Devices_Enumeration_IDeviceInformation@UIDeviceInformation@Enumeration@Devices@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QBE?AUhstring@3@XZ)
> referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
> st::OnConnectionRequested(struct
> winrt::Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect::WiFiDirectConnectionListener,struct
> winrt::Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect::WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs)"
> (?OnConnectionRequested@st@@QAEXUWiFiDirectConnectionListener@WiFiDirect@Devices@Windows@winrt@@UWiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs@3456@@Z) - error in Program.obj 1

What changes should I make at this line to clear the error? What does the error actually mean ? Or is there any other way to add an event in C++/WinRt project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `#include` directive:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
```

See [Why is the linker giving me a "LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol" error?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#why-is-the-linker-giving-me-a-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error):

> If the unresolved symbol is an API from the Windows namespace headers for the C++/WinRT projection (in the winrt namespace), then the API is forward-declared in a header that you've included, but its definition is in a header that you haven't yet included. Include the header named for the API's namespace, and rebuild. For more info, see [C++/WinRT projection headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis#cwinrt-projection-headers).

For general instructions on how to handle events see [Handle events by using delegates in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events).

---

Capturing `this` (raw pointer) into the delegate might be dangerous, too. This breaks the [link between object lifetime and visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11137516/1889329), and puts the burden of lifetime management on you. See [Safely accessing the this pointer with an event-handling delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references#safely-accessing-the-this-pointer-with-an-event-handling-delegate) for safer, more manageable alternatives.